# seleniumBox still not showing results despite capabilities being read

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I've configured my serenity capabilities in my serenity.conf file and it seems that the runner can pick them up. My goal is to have my test results to show in seleniumBox . I've included my token in the capabilities and yet the results do no show up. Is there some additional configurations I have do or do serenity configurations just not work with seleniumBox? I say the capabilities are being read because in my run output/logs I can see

```
"09:06:38.198 [main] INFO  n.s.c.w.d.ChromeDriverProvider - Starting Chrome driver instance with capabilities:
09:06:38.198 [main] INFO  n.s.c.w.d.ChromeDriverProvider - Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, e34:l_testName..."
```

with all the details I put.

```
capabilities {
browserName = "chrome"
acceptInsecureCerts = true
"e34:token"= xxxxxxxx
"e34:l_testName"=xxxxxx
"e34:pacAlias"=xxxxxx
"e34:video"= true
"goog:chromeOptions" {
args = ["test-type", "no-sandbox", "ignore-certificate-errors", "start-maximized", "disable-extensions"
"incognito", "disable-infobars", "disable-gpu", "disable-default-apps", "disable-popup-blocking",
"disable-download-notification", "disable-extensions-file-access-check", "enable-automation"]
#excludeSwitches = ["enable-automation","load-extension"],
}
```

that's how I've declared the capabilities

Comment: I was gonna delete this since it seems like a dumb question but someone who's also new to autotesting might have the same problem later. You just need to run the tests remotely and locally. XD